# Image not getting displayed in HTML document using JavaScript in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have an image url defined in my javascript code as:

```
var boxwidth = document.properties["sc:price"];
content += "<body align=\"center\"><font face= \"Comic sans MS\">";
content += "<b>Retail Price: </b>" + price + "<br><br>";
var urlStr = document.assocs["sc:relatedDocuments"][0].url;
//image document url
var res = "http://hostname:port/share/proxy/alfresco/api/node/content/"+urlStr.substring(4);
document.content = content;
```

I have to pass this as src attribute to an image:

```
content += "<img src=\"'+res+'\" width = \"65px\" height = \"35px\"/>";
```

Linking the url works this way:

```
var str = "View Image";
var result = str.link(res);
content += result+"<br><br>";
```

But I cannot see the image in HTML doc. Can anyone guide as to why it could be happening and what is the alternative?

Comment: Are you sure that your current user has permissions to access that document? And are you sure you're building the right URL?

Comment: Hi @Gagravarr, yes I am absolutely sure about the URL and the permission. I am logging as admin and viewing. There is some problem in passing string to JavaScript, I guess. Also, in Alfresco none of the normal functions of JS work like, innerHTML() or createElement() or getElementByTag().